# What colour space does Adobe Lightroom use when displaying photographs outside of the Develop module?

Tags: lightroom, color-management, color-spaces, adobe

I've already read [What colour space does Adobe Lightroom use in the Develop Module?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/53380/what-colour-space-does-adobe-lightroom-use-in-the-develop-module) this question but its leave two points unanswered:

1. Does Lightroom use that particular color space throughout or only in Develop mode?
2. Why, when I export this photograph as a JPEG, does the export using SRGB look most like what I see in Lightroom? If you look at these three images, the SRGB is significantly lighter (and I think better) than the other two (warning: large files):

Just tried making small images as suggested but I cant really see the difference now
but it is clear when you look at the ful size images.

[image: sRGB]
[image: adobeRGB]
[image: PhotoProRGB]

Full Images here:

- sRGB: http://www.jthink.net/jaikoz/scratch/colourspaces/srgb.jpg
- Adobe RGB: http://www.jthink.net/jaikoz/scratch/colourspaces/adobergb.jpg
- Prophoto: http://www.jthink.net/jaikoz/scratch/colourspaces/prophoto.jpg

Comment: I've inlined your images to make them easier to compare, but they're kinda large. Do you think you might downscale them a bit? I don't think that will change the demonstration.

Comment: Also, I notice that they're in a directory named "scratch". That makes me a bit concerned for the longevity of this question. If the images disappear, we'll be left with dead links.

Comment: @mattdm: i'm not sure it's so nice to inline 40MB of images, some people are on mobile phones...

Comment: @ths Yeah, un-inlined. Paul, could you provide smaller versions?

Comment: @mattdm Ive just tried doing that but now I cant see the difference !

Comment: the scratch dir is not going away anytime soon its existed for many years, but anyway whilst these are valid comments they dont really help with me understanding the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightroom uses Melissa as its color space, however it renders the image to your monitor color space. For many people this is close to sRGB. If your monitor is sRGB when you render to sRGB the prints will look the same. If you render to a printer with a wider gamut the prints will look different.

Answer (score 2):

Lightroom uses ProPhotoRGB/Melissa only in Develop module. The rest of the app [apparently uses AdobeRGB](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/help/color-management.html).

With regards to the brightness of those three images, I took the ProPhoto version and converted it to sRGB in a photo editor. They look pretty much identical, no difference in brightness. So if there is a difference in the sample images, either this is a Lightroom problem or the images were not converted using the exactly same workflow.

Comment: Thanks but could you see the difference in the export files that I provided.

Comment: Yes, I can see a difference in brightness in the files you provided. But we do not know how the conversion was done. It looks like if I do the conversion on my own, there is no difference of this kind whatsoever.

Comment: It was simply done using Export from within Lightroom, I'l try again to double check.